# How change details of an exe file using wix bootstraper?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe

I have a Visual Studio bundle file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle 
    Name="Some Name"
    Version="3.2.2" 
    Manufacturer="Some Company" 
    Copyright="Copyright: Some Company, Inc">
    ...
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

After build exe details menu contains two parameters (File description and Product Name) and these parameters have the same value. There is a way make these values different using only WIX functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Wix Version 3.10.2, you cannot set different values for the `ProductName` and `FileDescription` fields of the exe file description resource.

Looking at the WIX source code, specifically the file src\tools\wix\Binder.cs from WIX310-Debug.zip downloadable from [here](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/619491), shows the following code fragment for setting the exe file's resources:

```
        Microsoft.Deployment.Resources.VersionStringTable strings = version[1033];
        strings["LegalCopyright"] = bundleInfo.Copyright;
        strings["OriginalFilename"] = Path.GetFileName(outputPath);
        strings["FileVersion"] = bundleInfo.Version;    // string versions do not have to be four parts.
        strings["ProductVersion"] = bundleInfo.Version; // string versions do not have to be four parts.

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bundleInfo.Name))
        {
            strings["ProductName"] = bundleInfo.Name;
            strings["FileDescription"] = bundleInfo.Name;
        }
```

Notice that `ProductName` and `FileDescription` are set to the same value.

If this is important you could request a new feature via the WiX issue tracking database: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues.

Comment: See the [github source](https://github.com/wixtoolset/Core/blob/master/src/WixToolset.Core.Burn/Bundles/CreateBundleExeCommand.cs#L285) for a current version of that - still set to the same thing

Comment: Others have mentioned [Simple Resource Tool for Windows](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) as something that could be used to modify the properties post-build. It didn't work on our executable installer though...